# Javascript - Resize image to screen size

Tags: javascript

I want javascript to detect the users screen size and resize an image to fit the entire screen, but the user can scroll down to see more content.

I know how to use CSS to almost accomplish this:

```
position: fixed; /* or position: absolute; */
min-height: 100%
min-width: 100%
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
```

The image fit the entire screen, but I can't scroll.

---

Visit the link below for an example of what I am trying to do. See how the image fits your screen, and you can scroll down to see more content. That is what I am trying to do.

https://pixelgrade.com/demos/themes/?product=mies

Comment: Specify only the width, there is nothing else you can do if you want to scroll or it must be a little complicated with use of javascript. It's  possible but not only with css I'm afraid.For example when JS is enabled you can show it fixed with a background-size of 100% and when the users scrolls change it back.

Answer (score 1):

that's because of "position: fixed", actually you are scrolling but your image scrolls too. try "position : absolute;"

Comment: But min-width is 100%, so it still covers the whole screen

Comment: Maybe add a section with an z-index higher than the image?